# Match all two word substrings in a string,

Tags: regex

Let's say I have string with only lowercase ascii and whitespace, and I want to match all two-word-substring. For example

```
longString = 'this is a long string'
subStrings = ['this is', 'is a', 'a long', 'long string']
```

The core of my problem is that the substrings are obviously overlapping, and something like `/\b[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\b/` would match only non-overlapping substrings, i.e. `['this is', 'a long']`. I couldn't figure out recursion either. What is the approach here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?=(\b\w+\b)\s+(\b\w+\b))
```

[Regex101 live demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vS9Pq/1). This regular expression uses a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find all pairs of two consecutive words in the string, and captures each word in a separate capturing group. The `\b` anchors ensure that only whole words are matched.

As [Nuno André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775493/nuno-andr%C3%A9) pointed out quite accurately, if you don't need to separate each word into a different group within each `Match`, you can use the [following regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/DDCUOx/1):

```
(?=(\b\w+\s+\w+\b))
```

Comment: `/(?=(\b\w+\b\s+\b\w+\b))/` (with a single capturing group) returns exactly what OP asks for.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As @VadimMartynov explains, `\b` is not about greediness, but words boundaries. These pattern will return `['this is', 'his is', 'is is', 's is', 'is a', ...]`

Comment: @Nuno, I stand corrected and need to follow my own advice: always test. The inner word boundaries can be removed, however: `(?=(\b\w+\s+\w+\b))`.

Comment: Thank you all very much. I still have to fully understand it and apply it to my (slightly more complicated) use case, but this definitely gives me the right tools.

Comment: @oli hope regex101 will help you. You can read details of pattern in explanation panel on this site.